# CodeIgniter : cant get data from database

Tags: php, codeigniter

this is my views : alumni/loginalumni.php

```
<form action="<?=site_url('controller_alumni/login/submit')?>" method="post">
Username: <input type="text" name="username"/>
Password: <input type="password" name="pass"/>
<input type="submit"  /></form>
```

this is my controller : controller_alumni.php

```
public function login($submit = null){

        if($submit==null){
            $this->load->view('alumni/login_alumni');
            return true;
        }
        $username=  $this->input->post('username');
        $pass=  $this->input->post('pass');

        $this->load->model('model_alumni');
        $result = $this->model_alumni->login($username, $pass);

        if($result==true){
            echo 'LogIn';
        }
        else{
            echo 'LogIn Failed';
        }                 
    }
```

and this is my model: model_alumni.php

```
public function login($username, $pass){

    $query = $this->db->get_where('tb_alumni',[
        'username'          => $username,
        'pass'              => sha1($pass . HASH_KEY)
    ]);

    return $query->result();
}
```

when i run, and then i insert username and password and it say : "LogIn Failed"

Comment: try `print_r($result);` and check what you were getting over there

Comment: did you check after click submit its calling to your controller??

Comment: Its because you were getting an empty array..

Comment: $result = $this->model_alumni->login($username, $pass);

after this line can you please call this line:
echo $this->db->last_query();

Comment: thak you sir , ,  i've try it, and i have solve my problem, thank you for your help anyway , , ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the problem is on my `sha1($pass . HASH_KEY)` , , 
i dont know how to explain it, but when i delete `sha1()` its work !!

thank you for mr. https://stackoverflow.com/users/3555774/rishi for your clue ,, 
thank you so much , , ,

Answer (score 0):

Please change

```
public function login($submit = null){

    if($submit==null){
        $this->load->view('alumni/login_alumni');
        return true;
    }
    $username=  $this->input->post('username');
    $pass=  $this->input->post('pass');

    $this->load->model('model_alumni');
    $result = $this->model_alumni->login($username, $pass);

    if($result==true){
        echo 'LogIn';
    }
    else{
        echo 'LogIn Failed';
    }                 
}
```

To

```
 public function login($submit = null){

    if($submit==null){
        $this->load->view('alumni/login_alumni');
        return true;
    }
    $username=  $this->input->post('username');
    $pass=  $this->input->post('pass');

    $this->load->model('model_alumni');
    $result = $this->model_alumni->login($username, $pass);

    if(!empty($result)){
        echo 'LogIn';
    }
    else{
        echo 'LogIn Failed';
    }                 
}
```

Because if your user name and password is correct then it's return data not true and $result get that data . so please check this by empty()

Comment: still 'LogIn failed' sir , ,

Comment: please write 

echo $this->db->last_query(); 
exit; 
In model before return and you will see the query which has to be run . please copy that query and run into sql directly and see is that also not show any data

Comment: --- SELECT * FROM `tb_alumni` WHERE `username` = 'q' AND `pass` = '154a07fe7bb8a534d26379e6fcdb151f237164d4' ----

yahh its show nothing , , ,

so is the problem on my HASH_KEY ? or in my query ?

Comment: i've found the problom sir, the problem On my HASH_KEY, , , , when i delete the HASH_KEY, it say 'LogIn' , , , 
thank you sir for your help , , ,
thank you so much , , ,